# Backbone Views - Mocha - Targeting events in collection.fetch success callback function

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, mocha.js, sinon

When testing a `marionette compositeview`m in the `onBeforeShow` function, I am performing a `collection.fetch` with a `success` callback. However within the callback I then go on to clone my collection and attach events to it.

Now my issue is when testing this view, how would I target the various events/function calls I have set in the `success` callback of `collection.fetch`?
Is it possible or is it a case of not simply not being able to and code refactoring should take place?

If I set a `sinon spy` on `checkEmptyState` and then `add` a model to my collection created for the tests, the `spy` is not triggered, which makes sense as **I have stubbed the `fetch` method for the collection in the `beforeEach` function in order to prevent any api calls**. Which would be the best approach/set-up to enable testing the code within the `success` callback, if possible?

For example:

```
onBeforeShow: function () {

        var that = this;

        this.fetch = this.collection.fetch({
            success: function (collection, response, options) {

                if (!response.length ) {
                    that.addEmptyPostsMessage();
                }

                that.stopListening(that.collection);

                //Change collection property and re-apply events
                that.collection = that.collection.clone(that.options.filterAttr, that.options.isFiltered);
                that._initialEvents();

                that.collection.reset(that.collection.filterItems(that.collection.models, that.options.filterAttr), {reset: true});

                that.listenTo(that.collection, 'update', that.checkEmptyState);

            },
            reset: false,
            remove: false
        });
    }
```

For my test set-up:

```
beforeEach(function () {

  this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  this.server.autoRespond = true;

  this.collectionFetchStub = sinon.stub(My.Collection.Items.prototype, 'fetch', function () {
    return: {
             success: function () {console.log("this is never called!")}
            }
});
```

My `success` callback in my `stub` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure that you fetch stub executes it's success callback. Something like

```
var collection = [...],
    response = 'ok';

this.collectionFetchStub = sinon.stub(My.Collection.Items.prototype, 'fetch', function (options) {
    options.success(collection, response);
};
```

Or when using a sinon fakeserver instead of using autoRespond you should try

```
server.respondWith([200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': 2 }, collection_json_as_string]);
```

Make sure that the response is valid json.

Comment: I had tried using a fake server but it still did not trigger the success callback, even when I returned a 200 OK in the servers response. 

The fetch stub was simply a stub on the collection.prototype fetch method. I know that would not trigger the callback. I'll try adding the success callback to stub itself and see how that works.

Comment: I took a look at the fetch arguments again and edited my answer.

Comment: I have updated my question. Even if I do stub my fetch method and have it return a success function, this is never reached for some reason. Could it be because it is in the `onBeforeShow` function? I have tried calling `onBeforeShow` manually in the test suit and still the success callback is never reached.